# How can you run a jquery function inside a plugin from outside the plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I run "._openclose()" in the following swatchbook function for example?

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SwatchBook/index3.html

I tried stuff like:

```
$( '#sb-container' ).swatchbook = function () {
    this._openclose()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of useful information in the documentation for this plugin on [this page](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/07/02/swatch-book-with-css3-and-jquery/). The jQuery stuff is towards the bottom.

Without having used the plugin, I'm not sure how it works exactly but I can see right off that your 'this' is not a jQuery object. Try:

```
$( '#sb-container' ).swatchbook = function () {
    $(this)._openclose()
});
```

OR

```
$( '#sb-container' ).swatchbook = function () {
    _self._openclose()
});
```

_self is declared as the variable 'this' in the plugin:

```
var _self = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger event over item as specified by `closeIdx : 11` line.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#sb-container' ).swatchbook( {
        // number of degrees that is between each item
        angleInc    : 15,
        neighbor    : 15,
        // if it should be closed by default
        initclosed  : true,
        // index of the element that when clicked, triggers the open/close function
        // by default there is no such element
        closeIdx    : 11
    } ); 

});

function test(){
    $('.sb-toggle').trigger('click');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test" onclick="test();">Test</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it working without an internal toggle link, just an external link to toggle